# Django - Template tags inside css file

Tags: python, css, django

I'm trying to modify the css of a page based on the `PageSetting` model that I'm using. I'm allowing the user the ability to change how the theme of a page looks like based on some of the `PageSetting` attributes.

```
class PageSettings(SingletonModel):
    theme = models.IntegerField(choices=THEMES,
                                verbose_name=_("Theme"),
                                default=0)
    base_color = RGBColorField(blank=False,
                               verbose_name=_("Base color"),
                               default="bc0000")

    ...
```

What I would like to do is change some values in my css depending on `base_color`. Pretty much something like this:

```
# inside my_theme.css
.side-bar {
  background: {{ pagesetting.base_color }};
  float:left;
  width: {{ pagesetting.sidebar_width}}%

  ...

}
```

is this acheivble in Django? I know I can do

`<div class="sidebar" style='background-color:#{{pagesetting.base_color}};'>`

but this makes my html ugly and harder to debug.

Comment: You could do it within a `<style>` tag, but I'm not sure if that's best practice

Comment: Isn't this a job for `S(A|C)SS` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could do it within a `<style></style>` tag in your view file

```
<style>
    .side-bar {
       background: {{ pagesetting.base_color }};
       float:left;
       width: {{ pagesetting.sidebar_width }};

       ...

    }
</stlye>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to modify the css itself, you'll have to set the properties in the html. I believe a good way to do so is to add a predefined css class to your element. That is, in your css, you'll have one class for each style you want, and you'll add the one you want in your html.

Code example:

```
<div class={{ my_style_class_red }}>
 ....
</div>
```

Edit: if you have a large number of options (for example, if you want to customize the size of an element), you should use the `<style>` tag and modify its parameters with your python variables.

Code example:

```
<style>
   h1 {color:{{my_color}};}
   p {color:blue;font-size:{{my_font_size}};}
</style>
```

Comment: I thought about this too, but if one of the settings (namely sidebarwidth) is completely customizable then you'd need a semi-infinite number of classes which seems bizarre to me. This would work if you had like four or five different options though.

Comment: In that case, you should modify the <style> tag, and set the parameters you want using your python variables. In my previous answer, I was assuming you wanted to do change only simple values with a very small number of options.

Comment: You could also modify the style within the element tag, such as <div style='color:{{my_color}};'>, but as pointed out by @wilbur, you already said you didn't want to use that.

Answer (score 1):

do it in  label `<style>` but use "var" in css, so your html does not detect errors

```
<style>
  :root {
    --color: {{object.color}};
  }
  li:before{
    content: "\2022";
    color: var(--color);

  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, for me I had to use style tag inside base.html

```
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: "Booter - Zero Zero";
    src: url('../static/fonts/Booter\ -\ Zero\ Zero.woff') format('woff'), url('../static/fonts/Booter\ -\ Zero\ Zero.woff2') format('woff2');

    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.main-header {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
    background-image: url(static/images/header_background.jpg);
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```